# In IBM Event Streams SaaS on Cloud, where can I look for failing client connection attempts?

Tags: ibm-datapower, ibm-eventstreams

I am trying to configure a Kafka client (it happens to be a DataPower appliance running V10) to my IBM Event Streams SaaS instance in IBM Cloud. But the Kafka client keeps throwing an error:

> Broker transport failure Initialization failed

Where can I go, in IBM Event Streams SaaS, to determine if I can see my Kafka client trying to make connection ? And, ideally, see some useful error messages like "pwd is wrong" !

Comment: Can you specify which client you are using and the configuration you've set? If your credentials are wrong you woukd get a message saying so, here it looks like your client is not connecting to the brokers at all.
I also recommend checking our samples where we demonstrate how to use the most common kafka clients: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/event-streams-samples

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I managed to get it working - turned out there was some fundamental errors in my configuration, and the client was, indeed, not even trying to connect to the brokers properly.

As I said in my questions, my client is an IBM DataPower Gateway, using its built-in Kafka client. I intend to write up my experiences; they could be included in your documentation (because DataPower as a client has only been possible since mid June 2020).